# GPS NMEA data always available/reliable?

Tags: android, gps, location, nmea

There is a method in `LocationManager`
to register listener for GPS device NMEA messages listening via
[`GpsStatus.NmeaListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener.html)

Could developer be sure that [`onNmeaReceived`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.NmeaListener.html#onNmeaReceived(long,%20java.lang.String)) function will be called for every device with Android 4.1+ and hardware GPS?

I mean if listening for location changes is reliable in case of using and parsing NMEA data on my own instead of using [`LocationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) like I'm currently doing?

I'm asking because I found some old topics where developers were complaining about this method on Androids with 2.3 version. What about now/never devices?

Answer (score 0):

> Could developer be sure that onNmeaReceived function will be called for every device with Android 4.1+ and hardware GPS?

Not all GPS units use NMEA.  There are other major protocols in use.  I wouldn't bank on this being available 100% of the time.